# Api twitter issue

Tags: javascript, rest, twitter

I'm trying to use codebird.js to make a retweet by api but I receive ever:

```
Can't find HTTP method to use for "statuses/retweet/472453099303342100".
undefined https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweet/472453099303342100.json 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

I can't know the reason.

This is my code:

```
cb = new Codebird;
        cb.setConsumerKey("1CxzYhwF**Bu1lmfA", "YedD2cWkDM217Vw**Mduzya54s");//fissi per tutti utenti

        cb.setUseProxy(false);

        cb.setToken("2530776530-9zw**VZQZcLrfkrX", "rs5VkZD4ePZ9**hwLdzc");//accesstoken e accesstokensecret
        console.log("retweet");

        console.log(this.model.id);

        var id=this.model.id;
         var params = {
          id: that.model.id,

         };


    cb.__call(
        "statuses_retweet_"+id,

        function (reply) {
       //params,
         console.log(reply);
        // return reply;

        }
    );
```

I can't understand if is an authentication error or a bad rest url.

Comment: I suggest you print out the request response. If you have an authentication issue, it will look something like this: `{"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}`

Comment: "Could not authenticate you", this is the message but I'am authenticated, is this a method to check my authentication? @bluejamesbond

Comment: Can I retweet a post of a person that I don't follow? @bluejamesbond

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities.

1. The user may not allow you to retweet them.
2. Your authentication data may not be correct.

Assuming you are able to perform other Twitter actions without problem, what happens when you try retweeting someone else?